# Why is my chart tilted like this?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mschart

I dont know why my charts are tilted like this
[image]

this is the code i used in charting them

```
DrawChart(chart12Month, SeriesChartType.Column, _dt12MonthOrders, "mth", "total")
DrawChart( ch12MonthCusts, SeriesChartType.Bar, _dt12MonthCust, "mth", "cnt")

Private Sub DrawChart(ByRef TheChart As Chart, _
                          Byval ChartType As SeriesChartType, _
                          ByVal TheTable As DataTable, _
                          ByVal XCol As String, _
                          ByVal YCol As String)

        TheChart.Series.Clear()
        TheChart.Titles.Clear()
        TheChart.ChartAreas(0).BackColor = Color.White
        TheChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightSlateGray
        TheChart.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True  

        Dim Series1 As Series
        For Each dr As DataRow In TheTable.Rows
            Series1 = New Series(dr(XCol)) '
            Series1.Points.AddXY(dr(XCol).ToString(), dr(YCol).ToString())
            TheChart.Series.Add(Series1)
        Next
End Sub
```

i need it to look like this not tilted
[image]

**EDIT**

Designer generated code

```
'
        'chart12Month
        '
        ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1"
        Me.chart12Month.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
        Me.chart12Month.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Legend1.Name = "Legend1"
        Me.chart12Month.Legends.Add(Legend1)
        Me.chart12Month.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.chart12Month.Name = "chart12Month"
        Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        Series1.Legend = "Legend1"
        Series1.Name = "Series1"
        Me.chart12Month.Series.Add(Series1)
        Me.chart12Month.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(398, 187)
        Me.chart12Month.TabIndex = 0
        Me.chart12Month.Text = "Chart1"
        '
        'chartPPN
        '
        ChartArea2.Name = "ChartArea1"
        Me.chartPPN.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea2)
        Me.chartPPN.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Legend2.Name = "Legend1"
        Me.chartPPN.Legends.Add(Legend2)
        Me.chartPPN.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.chartPPN.Name = "ch12MonthCusts"
        Series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        Series2.Legend = "Legend1"
        Series2.Name = "Series1"
        Me.chartPPN.Series.Add(Series2)
        Me.chartPPN.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(398, 187)
        Me.chartPPN.TabIndex = 0
        Me.chartPPN.Text = "Chart1"
```

Comment: what exactly you want to ask???

Comment: What is in your designer file for your charts?

Comment: @FloatingKiwi check the edits

Comment: that all looks ok. Set a breakpoint at the end of DrawChart and see what the values are for Area3DStyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a play with the properties of `.Area3DSty‌​le` such as `.Inclination`, `.Rotation` and `.Perspective` to customize the 3D orientation.